# How to connect from android to windows locally (XAMPP)

Tags: android, windows, localhost, virtualhost

I'm using XAMPP and I wanted to see what the result is in my android phone locally so I did what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779992/9182477) and I got the result but because there is a problem in loading js, css, fonts and other public files I couldn't get what the original version is. I opened my browser in my phone and typed: `192.168.42.111` however I want to type `mysite.local` and get the correct result. BTW it doesn't show the page correctly in windows when I use `localhost/mysite` but `mysite.local`.

How can I connect to windows from android device just by typing `mysite.local`?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that I'm using my mobile network to connect to the internet and it is hot-spotted.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use Xampp from a hot-spot.Xampp is a local virtual server an you have to be in the same network.

If you are in the same network, then I would recommend to use the `IPv4-Adress`.

To get it do the following:

1. Press Win + R
2. Type *cmd* in the command field and click OK
3. Type in your cmd: *ipconfig* and press enter

Then you have to search a little bit after `IPv4` in the cmd. If you have found it copy the adress and replace `localhost` (In your app you website) with it.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point or I couldn't explain it correctly. I have no problem connecting to localhost. However I want to connect with url which is `mysite.local` not `192.168.42.111` because if I use the IP it doesn't load public files like css, js...

Comment: You have to change path of  css, images, js file because may be default path you used is `localhost` and required path is `mysite.local`

Comment: As I said it's working when I use `mysite.local` but not `localhost/mysite` in my windows and not `192.168.42.111` in my phone